# Using "OR" against two indexed columns doesn't use indexes

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

In the query below, `from` and `tid` are indexes of the `replies` table.

```
SELECT * FROM `replies`
WHERE `from`="<userId>"
OR `tid` IN (SELECT `tid` FROM `posts` WHERE `from`="<userId>")
```

By using "OR", it seems that it does a full table scan (~3 million rows).
The `EXPLAIN` says that a possible key would be `from`, but then it doesn't use any.

However, in the query below, `frid_lt` and `frid_gt` are indexed. The two columns are in a complex index (frid_lt, frid_gt), but `frid_gt` has also its own index.

```
SELECT `mid` FROM `messages`
WHERE `frid_lt`="<userId>" OR `frid_gt`="<userId>"
```

And this query DOES use two indexes. The `EXPLAIN` says "index_merge" and "Using sort_union(frid_lt,frid_gt); Using where".

**Why does the first query not use an index merge?

Is there any improvement I can make to make the engine use an index merge as well?**

Comment: Is ``from`` on `posts` indexed as well?

Comment: You may want to add `CREATE TABLE` statements and exact output of `EXPLAIN` to the question as well.

Comment: Imagine you were allowed to make just one forward-only pass of a phone book, and someone asked you to find all the people with the last name Smith OR the first name Yvette. Sure you could easily seek to the Smiths, but that doesn't help you because you can't go backward and start finding all the Yvettes with last name starting with A, B, etc. Sometimes an index (seek) isn't the most efficient way to solve a query that has multiple filter criteria (or returns too many rows, or too many columns that aren't in the index, or ...)

Comment: @wolfgangwalther Yes, `from` is indexed (I said in the post).
@AaronBertrand I do understand that. However, by using the "last name" index, at least, I saved time searching for Smith. I guess the engine could be improved to do two lookups on the table using each index, rather than a FULL table scan using no index. I would be happy to tell that to engine with `FORCE INDEXES` or similar, to help it decide.

Comment: (phone book, continued)  While scanning for Yvette, it could trivially check for Smith, thereby doing it all in a single table scan.  Note:  Fetching a row costs a lot more than checking for whether to keep the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` does not optimize well.  A common workaround is to use `UNION`:

```
( SELECT * FROM replies WHERE `from` = "..." )
UNION ALL   -- or UNION DISTINCT if you know there are no dups
( SELECT r.* FROM replies AS r
    JOIN posts AS p  ON p.tid = r.tid
    WHERE p.from = "..." )
```

Notice that I also avoided the usually-inefficient `IN ( SELECT ... )`

For further performance, have these indexes:

```
replies:  INDEX(`from`)
posts:    INDEX(`from`, tid)  -- in this order
replies:  INDEX(tid)
```

(And note that the `PRIMARY KEY` *is* an index, so don't add a redundant index.)

In your second example, the "index merge" that you experienced may or may not be faster than a `UNION`.

**Oh, it's an UPDATE**

To optimize `UPDATE`, do two separate `UPDATEs` (no `UNION`, no `OR`).  One straightforwardly checks `from`.  The other is a "multi-table UPDATE" (see the manual) similar to the second select above.